# PCI Compliance Scanning Tool For Any Version Of Magento Site

Tags: magento2, magento-1, magento-enterprise, magento-community, pci

I am looking for a PCI Compliance scanning tool that can scan Magento websites ( Any version ) or Piece of Magento code. Please suggest.

I know there is a checklist available in DevDocs (https://magento.com/security/best-practices/pci-compliance-checklist-ecommerce-businesses) but is there any tool that can do the scan and generate a report?

Comment: PCI Compliance scan/check/verification is carried out by third parties, and includes the inspection and certification of personnel, equipment, buildings and the entire environment. and related to any organization that handles payment cards. Do not keep cards details in magento or on your server - thats all you have to do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will have a look.